# LINQ for getting list with occurrence more than 1

Tags: c#, .net, linq

there is a List contains below class

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

The original list and expected output look like below

[image]

It should fulfills below condition:

If a name with status = A exists (e.g. A1 & A2) --> remove other peers which contains the same name & status = I (it is supposed that only one status=A for each name)
If a name contains many status=I but didn't contain item with status=A, then only display 1 item with that name

It can be implemented by few for loops and remove the duplicated peers literally, The question is rather or not it can be implemented by a LINQ

Comment: Yes it can be implemented using LINQ.

Comment: Yes indeed it can be done in linq, however your question is innately confusing, and poorly formatted. also `if name only contains many status=I item, then only display 1 item` what one, the first?

Comment: You'll likely need `.GroupBy`, `.Select`, `.OrderBy` (or `.OrderByDescending`), `.Single`, and maybe have to implement an `IComparer<DummyClass>` (for the aforementioned `OrderBy`, unless you want to rely on boolean equality and sorting)

Comment: What if there are two with the same name and status A (by the way, I guess type for status shoudl be string, and from value int)

Comment: the expected dataset what it is expected. If it can be implemented, please try to show it at code, it is not a magician show lol. please make sure it is a linq (1 linq), thanks.

Comment: @SKLTFZ You're dealing with a community of people (programmers) who write software to strict specifications. You asked if it's possible 

Comment: the LINQ solution will be very ugly and unreadable/unmaintainable with these many conditions

Comment: @John LOL, i am asking question and expected valued answer. and you answered "it is possible" and you really think it is what i am expected.

Comment: @John and the "Yes it can be implemented using LINQ" really got 2 upvote. I highly suspect where are your reputation came from.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander: What makes the LINQ solution ugly by this conditions.  ;-)

Comment: @SKLTFZ Comment upvotes don't produce reputation. Giving helpful answers to questions (and asking good questions) does if people upvote those.

Comment: @Oliver you're right. Yours and Prestos solution look very nice. did not expect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
var list = new[]
{
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A1", Value=1, Status= "A" },
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A1", Value=2, Status= "I" },
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A2", Value=3, Status= "I" },
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A2", Value=4, Status= "I" },
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A2", Value=5, Status= "A" },
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A3", Value=6, Status= "I" },
    new DummyClass{ Name = "A3", Value=7, Status= "I" },
};

var aggregate = list
    .OrderBy(item => item.Status)
    .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
    .Select(group => group.First());

foreach (var item in aggregate)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - {item.Value} - {item.Status}");
}
```

It will at first order by status ("A" comes before "I") and then group by the given name. Due to this, the first element of each group will be either the first "A" entry or if that missing the first "I" entry.

Output:

> A1 - 1 - A
>
> A2 - 5 - A
>
> A3 - 6 - I

Comment: Nice solution. Only open question is, what value to take, if there is no "A". Maybe Order ThenBy(x => x.Value)

Comment: @Malior: Then it takes the first "I" (as in the case of "A3").

Comment: it reduced 30 lines of code to 1. end result there is more than 1 order by and more than 1 group by. thus the final linq implemented as "list.OrderBy(x => x.S1).ThenBy(x => x.S2).GroupBy(x => new { x.N1, x.N2, x.N3 }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();" but the trick is the same, thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is your LINQ to get expected collection:

```
collection.GroupBy(g => g.name)
          .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => (d.OrderBy(or => or.status).First()));
```

`collection` is the collection of all rows from your table.

And here is code to check it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class DummyClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    class DummyClassCollection
    {
        private List<DummyClass> _collection;

        public DummyClassCollection()
        {
            _collection = new List<DummyClass>();
            FillUpCollection();
        }

        public void FillUpCollection()
        {
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass(){
                name = "A1",
                value = 1,
                status = "A"
            });
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass(){
                name = "A1",
                value = 2,
                status = "I"
            });
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass(){
                name = "A2",
                value = 3,
                status = "I"
            });
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass(){
                name = "A2",
                value = 4,
                status = "I"
            });
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass(){
                name = "A2",
                value = 5,
                status = "A"
            });
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass(){
                name = "A3",
                value = 6,
                status = "I"
            });
            _collection.Add(new DummyClass()
            {
                name = "A3",
                value = 7,
                status = "I"
            });
        }

        public List<DummyClass> GetCollection()
        {
            return _collection;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dcc = new DummyClassCollection();
            var collection = dcc.GetCollection();

            var result = collection.GroupBy(g => g.name)
                                   .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => (d.OrderBy(or => or.status).First()));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the trick is as same as the above answer. Also the expected output should be better the same type as the input type(not dictionary ). Thanks